# How to check if one row in one table is in the other table using mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in MySQL. Both of them have two columns.
How to check if one row in one table is in the other table using MySQL?

For example,

```
table 1:
a, c
b, a
d, f


table 2:
a, k
c, a
g, m
c, l
```

How can I check if each row from table 1: (a,c) (b,a) (d,f) exist in table 2 and then create a new column in table 1 containing the times each row shows up in table 2? 
The order doesn't matter here, so (a,c) is the same as (c,a). So in this case, one row (a,c) in table 1 match one time in table 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.col1, a.col2, COUNT(b.col1)
FROM table1 a LEFT JOIN table2 b
ON (a.col1 = b.col1 OR a.col1 = b.col2) 
AND (a.col2 = b.col1 OR a.col2 = b.col2)
GROUP BY a.col1, a.col2
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89c17/1

Answer (score 2):

use `LEFT JOIN` so all record of `table1` will be shown even if it has no records on `table2`

```
SELECT  a.col1, a.col2, COUNT(b.col1)
FROM    table1 a
        LEFT JOIN table2 b
            ON a.col1 = b.col1 AND
                a.col2 = b.col2
GROUP BY a.col1, a.col2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be1bb/2)

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to mention that the order doesn't matter here. So (a, c) can match with (c,a). I think your code limit the order.